# Building inference engine to extract appropriate file from database

Tags: architecture, inference, inference-engine

I am working on numerical simulation software having a "reader" to exploit one simulation file.
According to user input and other parameters, i have to extract the appropriate simulation file from database and send it to the client.

- 1- is it appropriate to implement inference engine in my case ?
- 2- What is the most appropriate language/inference engine should i use ? I was looking on Java+Groovy and for drools.